# How to iterate through class instance

Tags: loops, class, instance-variables

Hi i'm trying to solve an simple problem but i don't know how to iterate through class instances i. e.

```
class element :
    def __init__(self, a, s, m):
        self.name = a ;
        self.symbol = s;
        self.atomic_mass = m ;

class correction :
    def __init__(self, a, atr, v):
        self.name = a ;
        self.atribute = atr;
        self.correct_value = v ;

nitrogen = element("Nitrogen", "N", 12)

correction1 = correction("Nitrogen", "atomic_mass", 14)
```

and all i want to do is to FIND if there is an "atomic_mass" in class and if there is change it into 14. I'm trying to figure this one out for a while now.

Ofcourse finally there will be a list of elements = [nitrogen, carbon, helium, oxygen etc.] and I need to find correct one and change it's value.

So far I have this:

```
def correct(elements, correction):
    for i in elements:
        for j in correction:
           if i.a == j.a:
```

...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setattr()` builtin method.
For example:

```
class a:
   def __init__(self, a: str, b: str):
       this.a = a
       this.b = b

inst = a("str1", "str2")

setattr(inst, "a", "new_string_1")
```

or simply `inst.a = "new_string_1"`

**EDIT**

- to check if class has attribute you can use `hasattr` builtin method
- to iterate class props use `dir` builtin method

**EDIT** 


And finally, if you have list of classes, you can write correction method that takes a list of Element and list of correction rules. For example:

```
correction_rules = [
    {"attr": "atomic_mass", "search": 1, "change_to": 2}, 
    {"attr": "Name", "search": 1, "change_to": 2}
]

def correct(objects, rules):
    for obj in objects:
        for rule in rules:
            if hasattr(obj, rule["attr"]) and \
                getattr(obj, rule["attr"]) == rule["search"]:
                setattr(obj, rule["attr"], rule["change_to"])

correct(your_list_of_objects, correction_rules)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answear, i used setattr() and it worked perfectly

```
def correct(elements, correction):
    for i in elements:
        for j in correction:
           if i.a == j.a:
               setattr(i,j.atr,j.v)
```